# Custom post type permalink returns 404 when set to private

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, 404-error, private

I have a custom post type that is configured to use a permalink structure prepended with the post type name. When using `get_permalink()`, the URL that is returned does not include the post type name. This is virtually identical to the scenario described in [this question](/questions/288112/custom-post-type-permalink-missing-post-type-front).

```php
register_post_type('activity', [
  ...
  'public' => true,
  'rewrite' => [
    'slug' => 'activities',
    'with_front' => true,
  ],
]);
```

The permalink should take the form `http://example.com/activities/the-activity-title`, whereas `get_permalink()` returns `http://example.com/the-activity-title`.

Usually, WordPress does a pretty good job of guessing the correct post that should be displayed, and redirects the former to the latter. However, if the post is set to be private, that first URL results in a 404, even though the second URL is visible to the logged in user.

1. Is it normal for `get_permalink()` to omit the post type slug from the URL it returns, resulting in a redirect? If not, what's causing it?
2. If it is normal, how can I fix the 404 so it also redirects for logged in users?

The code I'm working with is all defined in a custom plugin. The `register_post_type()` snippet above is called by an `init` hook action, while the problem `get_permalink()` calls are in the `plugins_loaded` hook action.

The author of the question linked above states that his issues was caused by querying the permalink before the post type had been registered. Are the hooks I'm using in my code sufficient to avoid this cause?

Comment: Haven't fully delved yet, but I wonder if, instead of the `public` attribute, you need to configure the more fine-grained attributes, like `show_in_nav_menus, show_ui, exclude_from_search, publicly_queryable`. I bet that's not the full story, though.

Comment: I am already using the `public` attribute in my `register_post_type()` call, and it is set to `true`. However, I'm talking about setting an individual post's visibility using the *Visibility* option in the edit post page of the admin area. Some posts of this post type will be public and some will be private. The ones set to private are causing the issue described above.

Comment: I've added `'public' => true` to my question to improve clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was indeed the same as in the question I linked, in that the `get_permalink()` call was happening before the post type was registered. I confirmed this when trying to write a work-around that used `get_post_type_object()`, which worked fine in `functions.php` but returned `null` when moved into my plugin.

By referring to the [action reference page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) in the WordPress documentation (which, although it doesn't mention it, is sorted by the firing sequence of the actions) I could see that the action I was using to get the permalink, `init` is fired after the one I was using for registering the post type, `plugins_loaded`.

By moving the code using `get_permalink()` to the `init` action, I was able to fix the problem, and now the correct URLs are being returned, with the post type slug as expected.